# Zsh prompt's history number sometimes increments after ignored commands

Tags: command-line, zsh

When displaying the history number of the next command in zsh's prompt (I'm on version 5.0.2), it is unexpectedly incremented after ignored `histignorespace` and `histnostore` commands (and then only "corrects" itself after the *next* command) but works as I'd expect after ignored `histignoreddups` commands.

Is there a good reason for the difference in behavior?  Can I make the prompt consistently show the history event for the next (not ignored) command, even if it is following an ignored "spaced" or `history` command?

`histignorespace` suprises me:

```
% PROMPT='%! >' zsh --no-rcs --histignorespace
1 > true ignore me
2 >true two
2 >history
    1  true two
```

As does `histnostore` (also I thought it odd the immediate invocation includes itself):

```
% PROMPT='%! >' zsh --no-rcs --histnostore
1 >history
    1  history
2 >true two
2 >history
    1  true two
```

But `histignoredups` works as I'd expect:

```
% PROMPT='%! >' zsh --no-rcs --histignoredups
1 >true repeated
2 >true repeated
2 >true two
3 >history
    1  true repeated
    2  true two
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good reason for the difference in behavior?

Yes.  The Z Shell is behaving as documented in its manual:

> Note that the command lingers in the internal history until the next command is entered before it vanishes, allowing you to briefly reuse or edit the line.

Read the `zshoptions` manual for full information.

Comment: I did read that, and you're right to point it out as the likely underlying reason why ignorespace and nostore share the behavior, but I'm not sure if that counts as a "good reason".  Couldn't I also argue zsh is **not** behaving [as documented](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion) where it describes the prompt expansion as "the number that is to be assigned to the next command"?